# Ambiguous type variable

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

Related to [my earlier question on traversing data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855371/avoiding-boilerplate-when-dealing-with-many-unrelated-types), I'm having a problem making my code generic when I use it along with the uniplate package. I'm dealing with the data structures in the [Language.Exts.Annotated.Syntax](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/haskell-src-exts/1.1.4/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Exts-Annotated-Syntax.html) module, which are all generic with a type parameter `l`. This `l` is the same throughout the tree.

The kind of code I'm writing is like this:

```
doInt :: Child1 l -> Child1 l
doInt (Child1 l n) = Child1 l (n + 1)

doString :: Child2 l -> Child2 l
doString (Child2 l (_:s)) = Child2 l ('j' : s)

replace :: Data l => Parent l -> Parent l
replace = transformBi doInt
        . transformBi doString
```

This code produces the following error on both of the last two lines:

> ```
> Ambiguous type variable `l' in the constraint:
>   `Data l' arising from a use of `transformBi' at Test.hs:31:10-52
> Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
> ```

I can see why this code is ambiguous: `transformBi` accepts a `(to -> to)` and `from` and turns it into a `from`; in my case there's no link between the `l` in `Child1 l` and the `l` in `Parent l`. What I don't see is how to fix it. I've tried adding a type constraint like `transformBi (doInt :: Child1 l -> Child1 l)`, but I get the same error; it's as if I'm introducing a new `l` when I do this.

How can I tell the compiler that I'm using the same `l` for `replace`, `transformBi doInt` and `transformBi doString`?

**Edit:** [Here is the full program that demonstrates what I'm doing](http://gist.github.com/251520). Under GHC 6.10.4, this program fails to compile, with the above error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you need the [scoped type variables](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables) extension.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

replace :: forall l. Data l => Parent l -> Parent l
replace = transformBi (doInt :: Child1 l -> Child1 l)
        . transformBi (doString :: Child2 l -> Child2 l)
```

Note that quantification *must* be explicit to bring `l` into scope.

Answer (score 0):

`l` should be of same type in function `replace`:
Define it like:

```
data L = LInt Integer| LString String
```

See, `replace` can't be a polymorphic function. It uses strict types. This types defined by operations:

```
Prelude> :t (+)
(+) :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

and

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

and

```
Prelude> :t 'c'
'c' :: Char
```

To make replace polymorphic you have to make it of polymorphic functions.

Comment: I can't change the types that replace deals with because they come from another package: see the earlier question I linked to. The purpose of uniplate is to allow you to write a generic function across any data structure. I'll post the code to clarify.

Comment: This is what polymorphic functions are used for. Please tell me what is the purpose of `replace` function, it not clear for me. And type signature for `transformBi`

Comment: transformBi :: (b -> b) -> a -> a. It's part of the uniplate package: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/uniplate/latest/doc/html/Data-Generics-Biplate.html#v:transformBi

Comment: In this example, I'l using it to walk a tree of type Parent and perform operations on nodes of type Child1 and Child2. The process is analogous to reflection in .NET.