# Using generic type based on options

Tags: haskell, generic-programming

(Compared to previous versions of the question the examples have been greatly reworked and stripped of any — unimportant — crud. For example I left out the class "Marshalable" that is resembling Show closely. Thanks to the commenters.)

I have been pounding on it for quite a while, but am still not able to get it sufficiently generic to make it look good. I want to use flags and option values to control the input variables and functions used and feed the results into a generic "Marshallable" class. The Marshallable class replaces show in the sense, that it can use different functions in order to generate different string types for output (for example CSV values).

Actually I intend to call this marshal function only once within the main function, but I seem to be a far cry from that.

The main problem seems to be, that I am not able to determine the return type of the workers in a way that is sufficiently generic. Or I am thinking in the wrong direction entirely. Following is the unsatisfactory solution to a worker, where I repeatedly have to mention that I do want to have something marshaled, instead of having some result returned which then is marshaled.

To satisfy the repeated requests I have tried to water down the whole code to some complete minimum, without destroying the question. The code works with the following solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XFlexibleContexts #-}

import Data.List

data Strategy = H | O deriving (Eq, Show)
data Abstraction = P | S deriving (Eq,Show)

printSequenceAnalysis:: Abstraction ->  [[(Float,Float)]] -> IO ()
printSequenceAnalysis a traces = let 
  sequencer | a == P =  show.doSomething
            | a == S =  show.doSomething.strategies
    where 
      strategies t = [[H,H,O],[O],[O,H,O]] -- static example [[(Float,Float)]] -> [[Strategy]]
    in  putStrLn $ sequencer traces


doSomething:: Eq a => [[a]] -> [[[[a]]]] 
doSomething xs = map (\t -> filter (==t) xs) xs
```

The crucial point is the repetition of show within sequencer. Depending on the value of a, the input type to doSomething is different. I imagine, that something similar to the following replacement for printSequenceAnalysis would be very much more beautiful, as show and doSomething would both be mentioned only once.

```
printSequenceAnalysis:: Abstraction ->  [[(Float,Float)]] -> IO ()
printSequenceAnalysis a traces = let 
  sequence | a == P =  id
           | a == S =  strategies
    where 
      strategies t = [[H,H,O],[O],[O,H,O]] -- static example [[(Float,Float)]] -> [[Strategy]]
    in  (putStrLn.show.doSomething.sequence) traces
```

I found a solution by changing the type of printSequenceAnalysis to

```
printSequenceAnalysis:: Eq a => Abstraction ->  [[a]] -> IO ()
```

But this solution I am not able to put to work in the original problem, which is, that traces are read from files beforehand, and inserting an intermediary (output) function is not doing the trick at all:

```
printSequenceAnalysis:: Abstraction ->  [[String]] -> IO ()
printSequenceAnalysis opts fs = do
  traces <- parseTraceFiles fs
  output opts traces
  where
    output:: Eq a => Abstraction ->  [[a]] -> IO ()
    output opts = putStrLn.show.doSomething.
```

Comment: Could you provide us with more type declarations? E.g., what are instances of Marshallable here?

Comment: Please try to modify your code samples to a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/). So that it'd be possible to compile it, run it and see what it does now and then better understand what you'd want it to do. To be specific example, what is `Worker` (in your current implementation)?

Comment: It might be that I am simply not understand the answers to the ["ambiguous type variable"-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865351/ambiguous-type-variable) sufficiently.